# how to write result with label.text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add 2 numbers and then show the result.

- BUT NOT with Response.Write(result); as I can't place it where I want.

I have this in my aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox label="tal1" ID="TextBox_Tal1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox label="tal2" ID="TextBox_Tal2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button_plus" runat="server" Text="+" OnClick="Button_plus_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="Label_plus" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

And this in my .cs:

```
public int plus(int tal1, int tal2)
{
    int result = tal1 + tal2;
    return result;
}    

protected void Button_plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int tal1 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_Tal1.Text);
    int tal2 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_Tal2.Text);
    plus(tal1, tal2);        
}
```

Comment: just a note: your method `plus` returns a value but in the call to it you are not using it

Comment: `label.text = result.ToString()`

Comment: Do you really need a function to add two numbers together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple, you just need to assign the result to the `Text` property. However, you shouldn't trust user's input, you should use `TryParse` instead

```
  int number1,number2;
  bool result1 = Int32.TryParse(TextBox_Tal1.Text, out number1);
  bool result2 = Int32.TryParse(TextBox_Tal2.Text, out number2);
  if(result1 && result2){
    // assign the result to the Text property
    Label_result.Text = plus(number1,number2).ToString(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Currently you're calling `plus`, but ignoring the result. I suspect you want something like:

```
Label_plus.Text = plus(tal1, tal2).ToString();
```

That sets the content of the label which will then be rendered within the response.

Not sure if it makes sense to have a method for `+`, or that it should be public, or that it should be called `plus` in defiance of .NET naming conventions, but that's a slightly separate matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button_plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int tal1 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_Tal1.Text);
int tal2 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_Tal2.Text);
Label_plus.Text = (tal1 + tal2).ToString();        
}
```

Will do, no need to write a separate function

or as suggested by @Sleiman Jneidi

```
int number1,number2;
bool result1 = Int32.TryParse(TextBox_Tal1.Text, out number1);
bool result2 = Int32.TryParse(TextBox_Tal2.Text, out number2);
if(result1 && result2){
// assign the result to the Text property
Label_result.Text = plus(number1,number2).ToString();
}
```